# Error when typing Matrix and Binomial coefficients

Tags: math-mode, errors

New guy here, I am just trying to study LaTeX from the very beginning. I am using TexShop on a Mac, and now I am reading  *George Grätzer's Short Course*.

Here's my question, when I type Binomial coefficients or Matrices in TexShop, I get an error. What's my problem?

This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
%\geometry{landscape}                       
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           
\usepackage{graphicx}               
                            %convert eps --> pdf in  pdflatex       
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{}                            

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}


\[
   \binom{ \frac{n^{2} - 1}{2} }{n + 1}
\]

 \[
                 \begin{matrix}
                   a + b + c & uv    & x - y & 27\\
                   a + b     & u + v & z     & 134
                 \end{matrix}
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `%` character in that line where you state  'convert eps --> ' etc. That is a comment line

Comment: @Christian Dear Sir, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed the Enter key too fast...

Comment: @Christian No,that's a mistake, in the origin TexShop, it has %

Comment: I meant, it should be a comment line.

Comment: @Christian Thank you Sir, and if may I, a stupid question. It seems TexSE does not support LaTex, am I right?

Comment: In what context do you mean, it does not support `LaTeX`? TeXSE does not show direct output of `LaTeX`, that's true.

Comment: @Christian Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the line `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble. `amssymb` is meant for special symbols.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
%\geometry{landscape}                       
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           
\usepackage{graphicx}               
%                            convert eps --> pdf in  pdflatex        
\usepackage{amsmath}         % Add this line!!!!!
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{}                            

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

\[
   \binom{ \frac{n^{2} - 1}{2} }{n + 1}
\]

 \[
                 \begin{matrix}
                   a + b + c & uv    & x - y & 27\\
                   a + b     & u + v & z     & 134
                 \end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir, it works! By the way, I think they should tell a newbie to add this line in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you used an oldfashioned documentation or some illdesigned template; nevertheless, it is important, that it works now.

Comment: @AveMaleficum -- gratzer makes this recommendation: "Use the `amsart` document class for all your articles." (first steps in latex, p.xvi) `amsart` automatically loads `amsmath` and incorporates `amsthm` and `amsfonts` so the user has no need to load them explicitly.  otherwise, `amsart` differs from `article` mainly in the structure of the front matter; the body of an article is, for all practical purposes, able to be switched between `amsart` and `article` with no requirements other than loading the aforementioned packages.